# Acura Dealerships Overfill Oil

Tags: oil, oil-change, acura

I have been to multiple Acura Dealerships within California (3) and I have noticed a common trend after an oil change. It seems that every single one of them overfills the oil past the max fill line.

I have a couple questions:

1) Since the distance between min fill/max fill is 1 quart, if oil is at red line, does that mean it is 0.5 qts over?

2) Could this cause long term damage?

3) Or is this a practice that is recommended as 3 independent Acura dealers seem to do the same thing?

Taken after letting car sit overnight on flat ground:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure *you* are measuring the oil correctly? Some (I don't know if this applies to Acuras) cars require you to check the oil right after running the car. If this is the case with your Acura and you've let the car sit before checking, it could be reading high. Just a thought as I don't really know, but you might want to check your owner's manual for proper technique for reading the dipstick (it might also have the procedure on the dipstick as well).

Comment: That's a very good point. I am not sure I am measuring the oil correctly. I have heard from online and from the dealers that the best time is after all the oil has drained down to the sump and that therefore the best time would be in the morning after the car hasn't been driven. However in the manual all it says is that I must let the engine be off for 3 minutes prior to checking. Would checking it after it has been run (but left off for 3 minutes) yield a lower result as not all the oil would have drained to the bottom?

Comment: It could give different results than what you saw with the overnight measure. You could always check it at the 3 min mark, then a 5, 10, and 20 min check to see if there is a noticeable difference. Really, overnight should result in a good stab and check. The only other thing I'd ensure is you draw the dipstick, wipe it off on a towel the first go around, then stab quickly (fully seating the dipstick) and pull out to see the results. This ensures there isn't any residual from engine motion or drainage still on the dipstick mucking up the reading.

Comment: I just checked at the 3 minute mark, it does sit lower on the dipstick, about halfway between the red line and the max fill mark (so maybe a quarter of a quart). I did notice that there was one or two bubbles. Is this normal?

Comment: That it is riding high is not normal, but not necessarily bad. I'm wondering if the techs are just in a hurry and not giving the oil enough time to settle, then adding more oil to top it off. Don't worry about the bubbles. I don't see them often, but I don't think it's anything to worry about.

Comment: Yeah considering that (by my past form of measuring the oil), all the techs have done the same thing it seems kind of odd that they all top it off a tad more than max fill. Thanks for the help!

Comment: My presumption they aren't checking it at all, rather they just "know" how much it takes and dump it in. Why don't you ask them about it?

Comment: Actually the first time I went back and showed them that it was overfilled, they said that its no big deal but they wouldn't mind draining a little. In the end they said that it was easier to just change the oil again (kinda wasteful) and basically did an oil change again (for free). Ultimately, after the second change the level was around the same (at the red line shown above). For the second dealer I mentioned this to them and they said that they would ensure it was exactly as marked but again it was at red line. For the third dealer I didn't bother asking them.